# Can X509SubjectName be included when signing Saml2AuthnResponse?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I've created a Saml2AuthnResponse and am passing it to Saml2PostBinding.Bind()

The X509Data node does not contain X509SubjectName although my cert obviously has one.
How can this be added?
Also, can the standard prefix "ds:" be added to all Signature nodes?

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            ...
            <KeyInfo>
                <X509Data>
-missing <X509SubjectName> should be here-
                    <X509Certificate>...cert data...
```

Answer (score 0):

The ITfoxtec Identity SAML component use the .NET libraries to add generate the response and add the certificate. I do not thing what you request is supported, I'm afraid.

You are welcome to do at pull request if you figure it out.
Github repository https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2